# SConstruct - SyntaxError : Invalid Syntax

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, compiler-errors, syntax-error, scons

So, i've been trying to compile a program using sconstruct, but i'm facing a problem.
I got the following error when trying to compile a program using *sconstruct.*

```
D:\RN ENGINE - REV #1\neo>scons
   scons: Reading SConscript files ...
   File "sys/scons\scons_utils.py", line 19
            except OSError, x:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried to look for the file where the error is occured, which is *scons_utils.py*, but i didn't manage to find it, and the documentation didn't helped me very well.
Is this a bug on the sconstruct itself, or i did something wrong? Thanks.

If something else is required in order to solve this, i won't hesitate to give it.

Answer (score 1):

`scons_utils.py` is not a SCons file. So it's likely part of whatever you're trying to build.

Likely you're using python 3.5+ with a newer SCons, and previously you were using python 2.7 and older SCons.

SO the issue you see (once you find the file) is python 2.7 vs python 3.5+.
Try running again with `--debug=stacktrace` which should hopefully give you the full path to scons_utils.py

Change that line to:

```
    except OSError as x:
```

Comment: It's probably worth running the 2to3 tool on SConstruct/SConscript files and on any added utilities like this, if they haven't been vetted for use in a Python 3 environment.  It usually does just fine converting the common cases like exception syntax, print statement -> function, etc. You should be able to find `scons_utills.py` since Python is finding it....